# Using Spring Kafka with LINGER_MS_CONFIG causes error

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm experimenting with compression with Kafka because my records are getting too large. This is what my Kafka configuration looks like -

```
public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs(int blockTime ) {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        //spring.kafka.producer.request.timeout.ms
        props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG,blockTime);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,10000);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.DELIVERY_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,10000);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG,1048576);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG,"snappy" );
        props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG,5 );
        //ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG
        log.info("Created producer config kafka ");
        return props;
    }

    public ProducerFactory<String, String> finalproducerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs(10));
    }

    @Bean(name = "commonKafkaTemplate")
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> getFinalKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(finalproducerFactory());
    }
```

If I comment out the line with    LINGER_MS_CONFIG
, the code works.

I saw LINGER_MS_CONFIG being used in an example, which said that compression was more "effective". What is it about LINGER_MS_CONFIG which causes an error? Is there some conflict with any of the other properties?

Comment: What do you mean "works"? What error are you getting?